# How to return string value from exec library to object array

Tags: node.js

When i try using exec library to output the value it like

```
    const testcase = ['0001_login.js'];
    const test = (testcase) =>{
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          exec(`node ${testcase}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
             try {
              resolve(stdout)
             } catch (err) {
               reject(err)
             }
          })
       })
    }
```

And the result will be

```
    "result" : "{ TimeTakenTest: [ { status: '0004 Time taken test fail' }, { remarks: 'Time taken to login = 16.778866 seconds' } ] }"
```

From testcase

```
    const data = {
        output : []
    }

    // Push value to array
    data.output.push({status}) // Pass/Fail
    data.output.push({remark}) // 0.43232323 seconds

    console.log(data)
```

And the return is always string, how to convert stringed object to javascript object array?

Comment: Did you try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify(object) would help.

Comment: the result still in quote eg: '{"TimeTakenTest" : ["status": "Time taken test fail"]"}'